# For a medium sized company, what is the best, most consistent way to schedule Python scripts which have to run every day?

Tags: python, automation, scheduling

The organization I work for solely relies on windows task scheduler for running their daily python scripts. However, this makes it hard to monitor all the scripts and can be a bit unreliable at times.
Also; I can't imagine that it is best practice for a medium sized company to use windows task scheduler to automatically run Python scripts.
What is best practice in this case? I heard from other that Azure is frequently used but this is not possible for us yet. I heard of applications like cron but it seems that these are mostly used for personal use.

Comment: Opinion based questions are off topic and recommendations are off topic.

Comment: Try using this. It is very powerful and can be used for a lot more use cases in your company  (https://www.broadcom.com/products/software/automation/automic-automation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you want a tool for Scheduled Python Tasks. I recommended **Apache Airflow**. Our company uses Apache Airflow too (it's completely free). It's a Scheduled tool written especially for Python.
It is handy for creating and orchestrating complex data pipelines with many scheduled options.
[image]

For a brief introduction, you can check this [blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-complete-introduction-to-apache-airflow-b7e238a33df)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your needs and your constraints, also you must consider costs.

However there are plenty solution that you can use:

- Windows Task Scheduler: it can be suffiscent except if you are
  finding it unreliable or difficult to manage.
- Cloud: Azure or another provider such as Amazon Web Services (AWS) or
  Google Cloud Platform (GCP), which also offer scheduled execution of
  scripts. for example with azure, you can create a "Logic App" that is
  triggered by a specified schedule and runs your Python script. You
  can also use Azure Functions, which are a serverless computing
  platform. With aws, there is lambda that I had tested, it is a good
  option to threat parallelism and to optimize costs.
- cron: cron is a Unix utility that allows you to schedule scripts or
  other commands to run automatically. I use personally to automate
  running some processes in Ubuntu system. For example, to run your
  script every day at 8:00 am you can use:

  0 8 * * * /path/to/script.py
- Third-party scheduling tools: There are also a number of third-party
  tools available that allow you to schedule scripts like Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

You should use some orchestration tool, like airflow which is open source.
You can schedule any kinds of job including python scripts and monitor the same using simple UI.

https://airflow.apache.org/

[https://medium.com/fintechexplained/python-scheduling-using-apache-airflow-5f466d9944d8#:~:text=Airflow%20has%20a%20scheduler%20that,and%20syncs%20with%20DAGs%20folder](https://medium.com/fintechexplained/python-scheduling-using-apache-airflow-5f466d9944d8#:%7E:text=Airflow%20has%20a%20scheduler%20that,and%20syncs%20with%20DAGs%20folder).